# Class C IP addresses

Tags: ip

I was reading on a website that:

> the only readily available addresses for medium-size organizations are /24s which have the potentially negative impact of increasing the size of the global Internet's routing table.

and on another that:

> If a single organisation has 16 class C: every internet backbone will need 16 entries, if they were of class B, they would be stored in one entry (??)

Can someone explain the tradeoff in giving out Class C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 16 class C subnet:

`222.204.1.0/24`
`222.204.2.0/24`
`222.204.3.0/24`
`...`
`222.204.16.0/24`

the router table will look like:

`222.204.1.0/24` to `con1`
`222.204.2.0/24` to `con1`
`222.204.3.0/24` to `con1`
`...`
`222.204.16.0/24` to `con1`

So, there is 16 entries.

If use class B net, just need 1 subnet to contain such host, assuming it's `128.1.1.0/16`.
we just need one entry:

`128.1.1.0/16` to `con1`

---

But, considering VLSM, one entry maybe contains so much host's address.(if address is continuous)